# List-View reading via JSON with no keys

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm using Sencha Architect for testing purposes.
I added a list view, connected with a store, connected with a model.
The store is configured to load the following JSON data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "blacklist":[
            "word 1",
            "word 2",
            "word 2"
        ]
    }
}
```

Every "word x" should be listed as a list item in my list view

Now i wanted to set up my Model. But a model does need "field names", which in my case aren't present.

If i'm using the following JSON data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "blacklist":[
            {"name": "word 1"},
            {"name": "word 2"},
            {"name": "word 3"}
        ]
    }
}
```

and giving my model a field named "name", everything works fine.

But how do i set up this scenario, if my JSON values have no keys to define in the model (as field/fieldnames)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you want to do with your result you aught to be able to modify this code to get what you are looking for.

App.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true
});


Ext.application({
    name : ('SF' || 'SenchaFiddle'),

    models : ['TestModel'],

    stores : ['TestData'],

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', {
            fullscreen : true,

            model : 'TestModel',

            store : 'TestData',

            itemTpl : "{blacklist}"
        });
    }
});
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('SF.model.TestModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

    config : {
        fields : [{
            name : 'blacklist',
            type : 'string',

            // **This is where you will parse out the values of 'blacklist'**

            convert : function(value, record) {
                console.log("value: ", value.length);
                console.log("Record: ", record);

                var returnArr = [];
                if (value && value.length > 0) {
                    for (var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
                        returnArr[i] = value[i];
                    }

                    return returnArr;
                };

                return "Could not Convert";
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('SF.store.TestData', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    config : {
        model : 'SF.model.TestModel',

        data : [{
            "blacklist":[
                "word 1",
                "word 2",
                "word 2"
            ]
        }],
    }
});
```

Please let me know if I missed something in the question,

Good luck, Brad

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this great answer. But i've got problems though. I added the "config" property to my model's field. if i output the "returnArr" it's outputted properly as ["word 1", "word 2"]. But my list only displays ONE list item like so: "word 1, word 2" Am i missing something?

Comment: I think i'm seeing the point:
The "convert" function only traverses over each item. At this stage, the item could be modified, but this is not what i'm going to achive.
What i'm going to achieve is, that the items get recognized as single items (in this case 3 items) by the list. But the list treats all items as 1

Comment: How much control do you have over the api? Can you adjust any of the results? I think what you want is possible without modifying the json result but it will be hacky.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no was to modify the api's output "automatically". I think i'll transform the data manually and serve it "statically". Thank you very much, now i know, that this example is not (unhacky) possible to solve :)

Comment: I think all you need is to be able to add a key for the 'word*' values, is that not possible?

Comment: Yes, i did that now. Instead of getting the JSON Data via Ajax directly, i wrote a PHP script which is using curl to get the data and than formatting the data with keys.
Thanks for all replies, though i think this would be a nice feature for sensa to implement (allowing no keys also)